# Can i offer worship/prayers in Shiva or Shakti temples after having meat and without bathing?

Tags: non-vegetarian, shaktism

Suppose, i am going to Assam's kamakhya temple (shakti peeth with lot of killing of animals for offering to devi), then can i eat meat and wash hands properly and then without taking bath, can i enter temple/pray devi in valid sense of shakt scriptures.
In bengal and assam, i have seen people largely not following any such restrictions.

whether that same i applicable in case of shaiva temple? hanuman temple(as he was reincarnation of shiva)?

Answer (score 3):

First of all,which meat are you talking about?

Was it offered to you from the temple itself as prasadam?If so,then by consuming it you will become pure as opposed to impure.

If not,then please read on the next few lines:

It is clearly stated in our Shastras that without proper Suchi(cleaniness), if a Punya Karma is done, then that karma bears no fruit.In your case the Punya karma is visting temples and offering prayers and worship .

[image]

> Souche yatnah sadaa Karyah souchamulo Dwijah smritah|
>
> Souchaacharavihinasya Samasta Nishphalah Kriyah||
>
> Meaning-Every Dwija's(Brahmin,Kshatriya & Vaisya) base(mula) rests in
> suchi(cleaniness).So ,they should always take care to maintain
> it.Because, works/rituals(kriya) bear no
> fruit(nisphala ) if done without suchi(Souchaacharvihinasya).-Daksha Smriti & others.

A human being becomes impure in  each of the following cases:
1)On waking up from sleep.
2)On evacuating bowels.
3)On touching dead bodies,attending funerals etc.
4)On having sexual intercourse.
5)On shaving,cutting hair,nails.
6)After applying oils on body.
7)After eating meat,drinking alcohol.

So,it is **mandatory**, that you bath. if after having done one of those above,you want to participate in a religious ritual.

> Duswapnam yadi pashettu vaante vaa khurakarmani, Maithuney preta dhume
> cha snaanameva vidheetate/ ( In the cases of viewing disturbing
> dreams, after vomittings for whatever reasons, after shaving and
> haircuts, after the act of feminine congress, and nearing and touching
> a dead body, one ought to purify by Snaana(Parashara Smriti).

[image]

> **Offences against the Deity (bhagavat aparādha)** These all relate
> to misconduct in a temple or shrine or inattention during ceremonial
> worship of an Icon. They are as follows;
>
> 1. Approaching the Deity without brushing the teeth.
> 2. Entering the temple or shrine after touching a menstruating woman.
> 3. Approaching a sacred precinct after visiting the cemetery.
> 4. Entering a temple or shrine wrapped in a blanket.
> 5. Weeping or lamenting in the temple.
> 6. Combing the hair, or clipping nails or spitting in the vicinity of the temple.
> 7. Carrying an umbrella while circumambulating the temple.
> 8. Sleeping or eating in the temple or shrine.
> 9. Seeing a corpse and thereafter touching the Icon without having washed the hands.
> 10. Touching the Icon after having touched a corpse without having bathed.
> 11. Touching a sacred icon after having sex (without bathing).
> 12. Sitting upon an elevated seat in front of the Deity.
>
> **13. Eating meat prior to worship**

Comment: "Was it offered to you from the temple itself as prasadam?If so,then by consuming it you will become pure as opposed to impure" How? Offering meat to Shakti is considered good?!! You learn something new every day. Ask Sri Ramakrishna that is it good to offer meat to Mahakali, he will explain why it is NOT a good idea.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria First of all Sri Ramakrishna is my Paraaparaa Guru.Salutations to Him.Secondly,see this answer:http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15135/did-swami-vivekananda-eat-fish-and-meat-before-he-turned-a-sannyasi-did-he-cont..Swami Vivekananada says about Sri Ramakrishna "About vegetarian diet I(Swami Vivekananda) have to say this - first, my Master(Sri Ramakrishna) was a vegetarian; but if he was given meat offered to the Goddess, he used to hold it up to his head.".So do u think he is holding in his head a thing that is impure?

Comment: I don't know in which Shakti temples Goddess is offered meat..may be they do in Tarapeeth and Kamkhya(as this question suggest).In any case i'm in favor of completely banning all forms of animal sacrifice from Temples.

Comment: Is it all good or belivable in 2019? I mean to follow all the old rituals after being in modern world?

Comment: These are some general rules to be followed during worship .. yes they are still valid or to be followed even now ..if someone can not follow them then that is a problem for them @PratikCJoshi

Comment: @Rickross but we are in 2019. We are beyond god!

Comment: We still need the sun who is the visible God .. without him there won't be life on earth @PratikCJoshi